# Node.js + Express.js : express.static not serving image (contains errors)

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, express

I'm trying to use express.static to serve an image at http://localhost:3000/logo/logo.jpg.
The image *logo.jpg* is in */public/images* and my code is:

```
    app.use("/logo", express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));
```

The page loads, but the image is broken. Firefox says: The image at http://localhost:3000/logo/logo.jpg cannot be displayed because it contains errors. When I look at the page info, Firefox tells me the image dimensions for logo.jpg are 0x0. I've tried using various images and different browsers, but they all have the same issue.

How can I get the image to load properly?

Comment: What's the response data from your server?  I bet there's an error or something.

Comment: Yes, check with your browser's web developer tools and look at the actual HTTP response and its content. Maybe you have something else sending a response before your static asset handler is reached?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get my directory with static files served, but when I started to use `path.join` it began to work as expected. Try this:

```
var path = require('path');
app.use('/logo', express["static"](path.join(__dirname, 'public/images')));
```

Comment: I have confidence in this answer: looking at times I've done this sort of thing in the past, it matches up quite well (e.g. "app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));")

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit. For some reason, if I placed the line:

```
app.use("/logo", express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));
```

after this code:

```
// load liveReload script only in development mode
// load before app.router
// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  var liveReloadPort = 35729;
  var excludeList = ['.woff', '.flv'];

  app.use(require('connect-livereload')({
      port: liveReloadPort,
      excludeList: excludeList
    }))
}
```

It didn't work. However, if I moved the app.use("/logo")... line before the liveReload code, it works.

Don't exactly understand why the position affected how the code works, but at least it does!

Comment: In Express 4, middleware/route handlers are executed in the order they are added to the Express app or router.

Comment: So why would the liveReload script loading before the express.static make the express.static not work?

Comment: It looks like `connect-livereload` does some monkey-patching, so it's possible it's mutating the output (incorrectly).